# How to show the dependency problem in the existing python environment

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, pip

I installed the python packages on Ubuntu by the following command:

```
# pip install --upgrade -r r.txt
```

**Here is the console output:**

```
Installing collected packages: protobuf

ERROR: pip's legacy dependency resolver does not consider dependency conflicts when selecting packages. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
apache-beam 2.53.0 requires packaging>=22.0, but you'll have packaging 20.9 which is incompatible.
ortools 9.8.3296 requires absl-py>=2.0.0, but you'll have absl-py 1.4.0 which is incompatible.
ortools 9.8.3296 requires pandas>=2.0.0, but you'll have pandas 1.5.3 which is incompatible.

Successfully installed protobuf-4.25.1
#
```

After closing the console, I want to reopen the terminal to check what dependency problem is in my system.

**Here is the expected output:**

```
# pip what_command_to_show_the_problem

ERROR: pip's legacy dependency resolver does not consider dependency conflicts when selecting packages. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
apache-beam 2.53.0 requires packaging>=22.0, but you'll have packaging 20.9 which is incompatible.
ortools 9.8.3296 requires absl-py>=2.0.0, but you'll have absl-py 1.4.0 which is incompatible.
ortools 9.8.3296 requires pandas>=2.0.0, but you'll have pandas 1.5.3 which is incompatible.
```

What command can be used to show the same `dependency problem` existed in the system?

Comment: Looks like a bad `r(equirements).txt`. The dependencies should be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `pip check`

See [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_check/):

> Verify installed packages have compatible dependencies.

If you want to check a virtual environment don't forget to activate it or run its `python`/`pip` instead of the base ones:

```
path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip check
```